Relation between operator calculus and Green's functions for constant coefficients PDEs
Motivation
My motivation for the question stems from the fact that inhomogeneous matrix ODEs with constant coefficients can be solved through the matrix exponential. The latter often arise from the discretisation of PDEs with constant coefficients. So I was wondering whether there is a way to write the solution of time evolution PDEs in terms of some "operator exponential", in order to be able to draw parallels between the two.

ODE Setting
Consider an ODE of the form (where $L$ is often a matrix discretisation of some spatial differential operator along with its boundary conditions):
$$\frac{du}{dt}(t) = L u(t) + f(t),$$
It is easily verified that the solution is given as:
$$u(t) = \exp(tL)u(0) + \int_0^t\exp((t-t')L)f(t')\,dt', \quad \exp(A) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!}.$$

Example: Heat Diffusion in $\mathbb{R}^n$
Can something similar be formulated for PDEs, in terms of operator calculus? For example consider  heat diffusion $\partial_t u(x,t) = \Delta u(x,t)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then can we claim that its solution is given as follows
$$u(x,t) = \bigl(\exp(t\Delta) u_0\bigr)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}(\Delta^k u_0)(x),
\quad u_0(x) = u(x,0)?$$
I can take the time derivative of this expression and verify that indeed $\partial_t (\exp(t\Delta)u_0) = \Delta\exp(t\Delta)u_0$ as desired.
Granted, the latter series would be defined only for $u_0\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, while the classical solution requires much less and is just a convolution with a Gaussian. So can it be shown that $\exp(t\Delta)(g) = G * g$? I suppose one approach would be to Fourier transform both sides and then show that the sum converges to the Fourier transform of $G$?

Heat Diffusion IBVP
Now consider a more general setting: I take an initial boundary-value problem
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\partial_t u(x,t) &= \Delta u(x,t) + f(t), &\quad& x \in \Omega, \\
u(x,t) &= g(x,t), &\quad& x\in\Gamma_1, \\
\partial_n u(x,t) &= h(x,t), &\quad& x\in\Gamma_2, \\
u(x,0) &= u_0(x), &\quad& x\in\Omega.
\end{alignat*}
In this case wouldn't the expression $\exp(t\Delta)u_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}\Delta^k u_0$ fail to capture the boundary conditions? How would I account for those? Below I study the corresponding solution through Green's functions.

Heat Diffusion IBVP: Solution in Terms of Green's Functions
From the identities
\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot (u \nabla v) &= \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + u \Delta v \\
\nabla\cdot (v\nabla u) &= \nabla v \cdot \nabla u + v \Delta u
\end{align}
one gets that $v\Delta u - u\Delta v = \nabla \cdot (v\nabla u - u\nabla v)$. Applying the divergence theorem yields one of Green's identities:
$$\int_{\Omega} v\Delta u - u\Delta v = \int_{\partial\Omega} v \partial_n u + u\partial_n v.$$
We can apply this to find a solution for $u$ in terms of the Green's function $G$ satisfying:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(\partial_t - \Delta) G(x,t,x', t') &= \delta(x-x')\delta(t-t'), &\quad& x \in \Omega, \\
G(x,t,x',t') &= 0, &\quad& x\in\Gamma_1, \\
\partial_n G(x,t,x',t') &= 0, &\quad& x\in\Gamma_2.
\end{alignat*}
Using the derived Green's identity I can account for the two spatial boundary conditions:
$$\int_{\Omega} G \Delta u - u \Delta G = \int_{\partial\Omega} G\partial_n u - u\partial_n G =  \underbrace{\int_{\partial \Gamma_2} G h - \int_{\partial \Gamma_1} G g}_{b(x,t,t')}.$$
Simultaneously from $\Delta u = \partial_t u - f$ and $\Delta G = \partial_t G - \delta_x \delta_t$  one gets:
$$\int_{\Omega} G \partial_t u - G f - u\partial_t G + \delta_x \delta_t u = \int_{\Omega} G \Delta u - u \Delta G = b.$$
Integrating both sides w.r.t. time and rearranging we get:
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \underbrace{\int_0^t b}_{c(x,t)} + \underbrace{\int_0^t \int_{\Omega} G f}_{d(x,t)} + \int_0^t\int_{\Omega} u\partial_t G - \int_0^t\int_{\Omega}\underbrace{G\partial_t u}_{\partial_t (Gu) - u\partial_t G} \\
&= c(x,t) + d(x,t) + \int_{\Omega} G(x,t,x',0)\underbrace{u(x',0)}_{u_0(x')} - \underbrace{G(x,t,x',t)}_{\delta(x-x')} u(x',t)\,dx' + 2\int_0^t\int_{\Omega} u\partial_t G \\
&= c(x,t) + d(x,t) + \underbrace{\int_{\Omega} G(x,t,x',0) u_0(x')\,dx'}_{e(x,t)} - u(x,t) + 2\int_0^t\int_{\Omega} u\partial_t G.
\end{align}
Rearranging I get the following integral equation
$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}(c(x,t) + d(x,t) + e(x,t)) + \int_0^t\int_{\Omega} u\partial_t G,$$
where $c$ accounts for the spatial boundary conditions $u=g$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $\partial_n u = h$ on $\Gamma_2$, $d$ accounts for the inhomogeneity $f$, and $e$ accounts for the initial value $u_0$.
Defining $a(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}(c(t) + d(x,t) + e(x,t))$ and $Tu = \int_0^t\int_{\Omega} u\partial_t G$ I can write the solution as
$$u = a + Tu = a + Ta + T^2u = \ldots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} T^k a.$$
Now if I try to match this to the heat diffusion solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $c=d=0$, and I suppose $e$ is the convolution with the Gaussian. There's a pesky $\frac{1}{2}$ in front though and an infinite sum with an integral kernel $\partial_t G$. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere, or maybe there's a way to simplify this by assuming that $G(x,t,x',t') = G(x,x',t-t')$. I have no idea how to relate this to the operator notation though.

Unfortunately, you can't just hope that power series $\Delta^k$ converge. If you want that $\exp(-\Delta t)$ makes sense, you should use semigroup theory. My favorite introduction for this type of parabolic problems is "Analytic Semigroups and Reaction-Diffusion Problems" by Lunardi, https://people.dmi.unipr.it/alessandra.lunardi/ At the start of chapter 1, it discusses the problem of (not) converging series.

@C.Hamster Thank you for the book recommendation. I agree that the sum does not have to always converge, but I suppose it would for a specific class of functions whose derivatives do not grow too quickly. But indeed, in the book you recommended, they seem to take a more general approach and define $\exp(t A)$ in terms of an integral of the resolvent. Maybe I missed something, but it seems like the analysis of heat diffusion in $n$ dimensions in the book relies on the Fourier transform, and the latter doesn't work for arbitrary domains $\Omega$. So I am still not sure how to handle this case.

The whole theory does not depend on the Fourier transform, but they use the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}$ as an example, because you can explicitly compute the solution.

@C.Hamster I got that part. But I could not find a constructive approach (maybe I missed it) for deriving the solution operator for arbitrary domains and boundary conditions. There were a few simple examples. I believe the focus was on showing that the operators are sectorial, and not so much about how one would go about computing $\exp(tA)$. I am approaching this from more of an application oriented perspective, so I would have liked to have more details on the latter. Nevertheless, thank you for the recommendation, it helped me realize that the series representation is not ideal.
